# Tensorflow errors "indices[0,0] = 3902 is not in [0, 59)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

First of all, I'm running on a crappy laptop (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz, 24 GB ram). I have a raspberry pi * 18 cluster that gives me the same response. I've spent the past 3-4 days just tinkering with the variables trying to figure out how to get this thing to work, but nothing I've done seems to have any affect.

First time poster, so if I made any mistakes, I apologize.
The script itself is

```
import csv
import gc
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit
from numpy import sqrt, sin, cos, pi, zeros
from numpy.random import randn, rand, uniform, normal
from scipy.linalg import hadamard
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, LSTM, Dropout, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Embedding, Reshape, Dot, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU, SpatialDropout1D, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D,Multiply, Lambda, Softmax, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Bidirectional, dot, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AdditiveAttention, Attention
from tensorflow.keras.activations import relu
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks
from tensorflow.keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.python.ops.tensor_array_ops import _EagerTensorArray
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from tensorflow import keras

AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU detection. No parameters necessary if TPU_NAME environment variable is set. On Kaggle this is always the case.
    print('Running on TPU ', tpu.master())
except ValueError:
    tpu = None
if tpu:
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
else:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()




inputfile = ('D:\\users\\rober\\downloads\\DGR.csv')

dgr = pd.read_csv(inputfile, index_col="DRAW DATE")
inputfile = open(inputfile)
csvreader = csv.DictReader(inputfile)
header = next(csvreader)
rows = []
inputai = []
outputai = []

for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
        drawnumber = row.get("DRAW NUMBER")
        year = (row.get("DRAW DATE")[0:4])
        month = (row.get("DRAW DATE")[5:7])
        day = (row.get("DRAW DATE")[8:10])
        date = (year, month, day, drawnumber)

        inputstuff = tf.TensorArray(np.array(date), size = 16, tensor_array_name = "Slibs")
        inputai.append(inputstuff)
        outputstuff = tf.TensorArray(np.array((row.get("NUMBER DRAWN 1"), row.get("NUMBER DRAWN 2"), row.get("NUMBER DRAWN 3"), row.get("NUMBER DRAWN 4"), row.get("NUMBER DRAWN 5"),row.get("NUMBER DRAWN 6"), row.get("BONUS NUMBER"))), size = 16)
        outputai.append(outputstuff)

data = dgr.values
train = data[:-50]
test = data[-50:]

w = 10
X_train = []
y_train = []
print("X and Y trains created")
for i in range(w, len(train)):
    X_train.append(train[i - w: i, :])
    y_train.append(train[i])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)


inputs = data[data.shape[0] - test.shape[0] - w:]
X_test = []
for i in range(w, inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i - w: i, :])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
y_test = test
print(f"Data Shape =  {data.shape}")
print(f"X_train.shape = {X_train.shape}")
print(f"y_train.shape = {y_train.shape}")
print(f"X_test.shape = {X_test.shape}")
print(f"y_test.shape = {y_test.shape}")


embed_dim = (59 // 2) + 1
dropout_rate = 0.5
spatial_dropout_rate = 0.5
steps_before = w
steps_after = 5
feature_count = embed_dim * 5
hidden_neurons = [64, 32] 
bidirectional = True 
attention_style = 'Bahdanau'

with strategy.scope():
    
    inp0 = Input(shape = (w, X_train.shape[2]))
    
    inp1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 0])(inp0)
    inp1 = Embedding(59, embed_dim)(inp1)
    inp1 = SpatialDropout1D(spatial_dropout_rate)(inp1)
    
    inp2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 1])(inp0)
    inp2 = Embedding(59, embed_dim)(inp2)
    inp2 = SpatialDropout1D(spatial_dropout_rate)(inp2)
    inp3 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 2])(inp0)
    inp3 = Embedding(59, embed_dim)(inp3)
    inp3 = SpatialDropout1D(spatial_dropout_rate)(inp3)
    
    inp4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 3])(inp0)
    inp4 = Embedding(59, embed_dim)(inp4)
    inp4 = SpatialDropout1D(spatial_dropout_rate)(inp4)
    
    inp5 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 4])(inp0)
    inp5 = Embedding(59, embed_dim)(inp5)
    inp5 = SpatialDropout1D(spatial_dropout_rate)(inp5)    
    
    inp6 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 5])(inp0)
    inp6 = Embedding(59, embed_dim)(inp6)
    inp6 = SpatialDropout1D(spatial_dropout_rate)(inp6)
    
    inp7 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 6])(inp0)
    inp7 = Embedding(59, embed_dim)(inp7)
    inp7 = SpatialDropout1D(spatial_dropout_rate)(inp7)
    
    inp = Concatenate()([inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5, inp6, inp7])
       
    num_layers = len(hidden_neurons)
    
    sh_list, h_list, c_list = [inp], [], []
    
    if bidirectional:
        
        for i in range(num_layers):
    
            sh, fh, fc, bh, bc = Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_neurons[i],
                                                    dropout = dropout_rate, 
                                                    return_state = True, 
                                                    return_sequences = True))(sh_list[-1])
        
            h = Concatenate()([fh, bh])
            c = Concatenate()([fc, bc]) 

            sh_list.append(sh)
            h_list.append(h)
            c_list.append(c)
        
    else:
    
        for i in range(num_layers):

            sh, h, c = LSTM(hidden_neurons[i], 
                            dropout = dropout_rate,
                            return_state = True, 
                            return_sequences = True)(sh_list[-1])

            sh_list.append(sh)
            h_list.append(h)
            c_list.append(c)
    
    decoder = RepeatVector(steps_after)(h_list[-1])
    
    if bidirectional:
        
        decoder_hidden_neurons = [hn * 2 for hn in hidden_neurons]
        
    else:
        
        decoder_hidden_neurons = hidden_neurons
    
    for i in range(num_layers):
        
        decoder = LSTM(decoder_hidden_neurons[i],
                       dropout = dropout_rate, 
                       return_sequences = True)(decoder, initial_state = [h_list[i], c_list[i]])
       
    if attention_style == 'Bahdanau':
        
        context = AdditiveAttention(dropout = dropout_rate)([decoder, sh_list[-1]])
        
        decoder = concatenate([context, decoder])
        
    elif attention_style == 'Luong':
        
        context = Attention(dropout = dropout_rate)([decoder, sh_list[-1]])
        
        decoder = concatenate([context, decoder])
    
    out = Dense(59, activation = 'softmax')(decoder)

    model = Model(inputs = inp0, outputs = out)
    
    sparse_top_k = tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k = 5, name = 'sparse_top_k')

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = [sparse_top_k])    

model.load_weights('best_model.hdf5')
X_test=np.asarray(X_test).astype(int)

pred = model.predict(X_test)
pred = np.argmax(pred, axis = 2)
for i in range(y_test.shape[0]):
    print('Prediction:\t', pred[i] + 1)
    print('GoundTruth:\t', y_test[i] + 1)
    print('-' * 40)
plot_model(model, show_shapes = True, show_layer_names = True, rankdir = 'TB', dpi = 60)
```

The error along with the shapes of the various relevant variables is as follows:

````
X and Y trains created
Data Shape =  (661, 9)
X_train.shape = (601, 10, 9)
y_train.shape = (601, 9)
X_test.shape = (50, 10, 9)
y_test.shape = (50, 9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\Python Stuff\csvpractice.py", line 210, in <module>
    pred = model.predict(X_test)
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model/embedding/embedding_lookup' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 163, in main
      ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 566, in runcode
      exec(code, self.locals)
    File "C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\Python Stuff\csvpractice.py", line 210, in <module>
      pred = model.predict(X_test)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1982, in predict
      tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1801, in predict_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1790, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1783, in run_step
      outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
      return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 451, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\embeddings.py", line 197, in call
      out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, inputs)
Node: 'model/embedding/embedding_lookup'
indices[0,0] = 490 is not in [0, 59)
     [[{{node model/embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_7250]```

My thought is that this entire problem is probably caused by trying to squeeze too much data into the package that I'm sending through the prediction function, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the case or how to remedy it.

If anybody could offer me a solution, I would greatly appreciate it.
````

Comment: Do you know how the Embedding layer works? Because it makes no sense to use it the way you are using it.

Comment: Sorry. I realized a few minutes ago that even with a few hours of reading that there is still much to be learned. I'll continue to experiment until I have a question worth asking, none of this stupid BS question stuff.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the keras examples and start with a simpler code.